# Defining the result of combineLatest once

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Is there a more effective way to access the array?

```
const combineLatestResult$ = combineLatest(
  firstObservable$,
  secondObservable$,
  thirdObservable$,
);

combineLatestResult$.pipe(
  take(1),
  takeWhile(([first, second, third]: [string, boolean, number]) => !second),
  tap(([first, second, third]: [string, boolean, number]) => {
     first;
     third;
    // do something
  }),
).subscribe();
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
...

combineLatestResult$.pipe(
  take(1),
  takeWhile((arr) => !arr.second),
  tap((arr) => {
    arr.first;
    arr.third;
    // do something
  }),
).subscribe();
```

In the takeWhile operator, I only need to use one of the items in the array. And after that, I will not use it anymore. Basically, I want to know if it's possible to name the array items once and then use it multiple times.

Comment: `map([first, second, third]=>({first, second, third}))` ?

Comment: Of course... so simple. I had to add an extra parenthesis so it became `map(([first, second, third])=>({first, second, third}))`. Thank you so much! :) If you could post this as a post, I could mark it as the answer.

Comment: If you already use `take(1)`, what's the point of adding `takeWhile()`? There will never be more than one result anyway. If you don't want the 1 result, you can use `filter()`.