# rxjs Error complaining about incompatible types

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

follow on to [SO 69670747](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670747/is-this-a-reasonable-way-to-queue-observables)

I have read a fair amount since getting some coaching in that SO. I am now down to an issue where TS is complaining about incompatible types. I am not seeing my mistake.

Note : I try to develop code so that the max amount is identical from source to source. One technique is to call the 'main' TYPE  'item' ( in this case... the main item type is  ProjRev).
SO here , any reference to 'item' will be pointing to a ProjRev object  (except for of course ProjectSvc.GetItemById)
That seemed to cause confusion in the last SO , thought I would at least clarify...

```
import { Component, OnInit,  ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
  import { Observable,forkJoin, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilKeyChanged, pluck
      , switchMap ,tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { Project } from '../project';
import { ProjectRev} from '../project-rev';
import { ProjectService } from '../services/project.service';
import { ProjectRevService } from '../services/project-rev.service';

 

interface  VM{
    projectRev : ProjectRev;
    project : Project;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-rev-detail',
  templateUrl: './project-rev-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-rev-detail.component.css']
})
export class ProjectRevDetailComponent implements OnInit  {
   private projectRevId$ : Observable<string>;
   private myItem$ : Observable<ProjectRev>;
   private myProject$ : Observable<Project>;


   public vm$ : Observable<VM>   ;
   

  constructor( private projrevSvc : ProjectRevService
          , private projectSvc : ProjectService
          ,private location: Location
          ,private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
       ) {

       }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.projectRevId$ = this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
      pluck('id')
      ,tap( id => {  console.log('pRevId',id);})
    );

    this.myItem$ = this.projectRevId$.pipe(
      tap( item => {  console.log('inside projrev pipe',item);})
      ,   switchMap( (itemId : string) => this.projrevSvc.getItemById(  itemId   ))
      , tap( item => console.log('rev retrieved',item))
    );

    this.myProject$ = this.myItem$.pipe(
      tap( (prev : ProjectRev) =>{  console.log('inside getProj pipe');})
      ,distinctUntilKeyChanged('ProjectId')
      ,switchMap((item) => this.projectSvc.getItemById(item.ProjectId))
      , tap( item => console.log('proj retrieved',item))

    );

     this.vm$   = combineLatest(

      this.myItem$,
      this.myProject$
   ).subscribe(([ projRev , project]) => {
    this.myItem$ =projRev;
    this.myProject$ = project;
});
```

the error message is

```
   ERROR in src/app/projects/project-rev-detail/project-rev-detail.component.ts(76,5): error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<VM>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 114 more.
    src/app/projects/project-rev-detail/project-rev-detail.component.ts(81,9): error TS2740: Type 'ProjectRev' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<ProjectRev>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 114 more.
    src/app/projects/project-rev-detail/project-rev-detail.component.ts(82,9): error TS2740: Type 'Project' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Project>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 114 more.
```

the service function that is being called is here...
this is working as evidenced by my log listing

```
 getItemById(id: string): Observable< ProjectRev> {
     console.log('inside proj rev getItemByid..');
       const url = `${this.serviceUrl}/${id}`;
       return this.http.get< ProjectRev>(url, httpOptions)
           .pipe(
             catchError(err =>
               this.handleError(`getItemById=${id}`, err))
       );

   }
```

I have tried changing the VM interface to be observables  and not observables.
I have done all the permutations changing the interface and the combineLatest parm signature
I am pretty sure this is where my trouble lies.

Question : There are no subscribes when I am initializing the observables in ngOnit();  I took this patter from an SO answer. Should there be subscribes?
I have previously made the mistake of not subscribing...is it not necessary here?

The VM pattern is not necessary. It was suggested in an SO answer. I definitely see the advantage of wrapping the whole UI in 1 ngIf...But only if i can make it work. Is there a name for this pattern I can google? Anyone have a good example?

Comment: if you have some nits... happy to serve, but i think it is formatted fairly well.

Comment: I'm just gonna list a few things most code-bases try to maintain some consistancy with: `private projectRevId$` is indented 2 spaces; `private myItem$` is indented 3 spaces; `public vm$` is indented 4 spaces; `@ViewChild` is indented 6 spaces... they're all the same scope. Your `constructor`'s arguments dodging left and right by 3 spaces. Throughout the code you start a line with a `,` followed by 0-3 spaces seemingly randomly? The closing brackets for your subscribe at the end of the code snippet line up with the class declaration and not `this.vm$ = combineLatest(`.

Comment: thanks , ill fix those. Any thoughts on the type mismatches?  thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```ts
public count : number;
initCount(){
  this.count = "Hello!";
}
```

Expected Error: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'`

That's because I first say count is a number, but then assign a string to it. How to fix this depends on the intention. Given how count is named, once might assume that assigning it a string was the mistake.

---

On to your code :)

```ts
public vm$: Observable<VM>;
ngOnInit(){
  this.vm$ = someObservable.subscribe(someLambda);
}
```

Here you're trying to assign a subscription to an observable. It's roughly the same error as above, but TypeScript will try to do duck-typing (look at the object properties and see if they match). Subscriptions and observables don't overlap.

That's what your error message is telling you.

How to fix this? The best way/ idiomatic way is hard to tell from what you've written here, but here's one way the types might align again.

```ts
this.vm$ = combineLatest(
  this.myItem$,
  this.myProject$
).pipe(
  map(([projectRev, project]) => ({
    projectRev,
    project
  }))
);
```

Comment: ERROR in src/app/projects/project-rev-detail/project-rev-detail.component.ts(76,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<VM | [ProjectRev, Project]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<VM>'.
      Type 'VM | [ProjectRev, Project]' is not assignable to type 'VM'.
        Type '[ProjectRev, Project]' is not assignable to type 'VM'.
    src/app/projects/project-rev-detail/project-rev-detail.component.ts(81,16): error TS2569: Type 'VM | [ProjectRev, Project]' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.

Comment: @greg Ah, you're right. Your types are even more misaligned than I thought! The solution is still the same. Change the type of the observable or change the type of your component's property.

Comment: hey thanks. Would it be possible to update your proposed answer to be correct. I obviously am missing something pretty basic here so ... an example would be awesome.

Comment: Sure, though I don't have your code to test anything. From my point of view, my updated answer looks closer to what you're after.

Comment: i am making progress here. :-).   I have myItem$ : observable<ProjectRev>.   should I be able to do {{myItem$.Name}} in the HTML template?   or should i map to an instance of ProjectRev.     this is really the base concept I have been struggling with.

Comment: this got me over this hump. now i am struggling w/ the ngIf. Ill asks another question. Thanks so much for the help.