# Angular data undefined outside subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscribe, mergemap

I know it was asked million times, but i really don't understand how it works. I tried to new Promise, but there is nothing inside `then()` i tried to do it with mergeMap but messed up.
I want to get current user's favorite items. And to do it i'm calling this method:

```
user: IUser;
tracks: ITrack[] = [];

public getFavorites() {
    this.userService.getFavourite(this.user.id).subscribe(
      (tracks: ILike[]) => {
        if (tracks) {
          tracks.forEach(track => {
            this.tracks.push(this.loadTracks(track.id));
          });
        }
      }
    );
```

For this method i need user id which i get like this and :

```
private async loadUser() {
    this.accountService.currentUser$.subscribe((user: IUser) => {
      // getting into another service, because currentUser don't have id
      this.userService.getUserByUsername(user.username).subscribe((u: IUser) => {
        this.user = u;
      })
    })
  }
```

and and also track_id:

```
loadTracks(id: number) {
    let track: ITrack;
    this.trackService.getTrack(id).subscribe(t => track = t);
    return track;
}
```

ngOnInit():

```
this.loadUser();
this.getFavorites();
```

How to do it properly with mergeMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will want to use `switchMap` in this case.

```
this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
    switchMap((user: IUser)=> {
       return this.userService.getUserByUsername(user.username);
    }),
    tap(user => {
       console.log(user); // Check if its work
    }),
    switchMap(user => {
       return this.userService.getFavourite(this.user.id)
    }),
    tap(tracks => {
       console.log(tracks); // Now you have track
    })
); // You can .subscribe() here or use async pipe
```

You also can split this logic and reuse

```
const getUser$ = this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
    switchMap((user: IUser)=> {
       return this.userService.getUserByUsername(user.username);
    })
);
```

Read more about Higher order observable [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/)

Comment: thank you for answer. However, im getting undefined if i want to get tracks `switchMap((track: ITrack) => { return this.trackService.getTrack(track.id) })` after `switchMap(user => { return this.userService.getFavourite(this.user.id)})`. `getFavorite` method returns `Observable<ILike[]>` and i want to get `ITrack` from ILike's id

Answer (score 1):

You may find it easier to understand if you keep everything as observables (*until you really need to subscribe*). We can declare each piece of data as an observable source, and then define one observable from another one.

```js
user$: Observable<IUser> = this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
    switchMap(user => this.userService.getUserByUsername(user.username))
);

tracks$: Observable<ITrack[]> = this.user$.pipe(
    switchMap(user => this.userService.getFavourite(user.id)),
    switchMap(tracks => forkJoin(
        tracks.map(t => this.trackService.getTrack(t.id))
    ))
);
```

Now, simply subscribe to `tracks$` to get the list of tracks.  No need for extra variables to store data in, no calling "load" methods or even using `ngOnit`.

Notice how the definition of `tracks$` begins with `user$`.  This makes it clear that when `user$` emits a new value (*`accountService.currentUser$` changes*), `tracks$` will emit the updated tracks list automatically.

Note: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69688433/1858357) helpful as the question involves a similar situation and the answer has a very in-depth explaination.

Comment: that's more clear now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`. `mergeMap` should be used when you want to combine the results of observables.

Here is a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sdf2gy?file=index.ts

```
let userLocation$ = of({ userId: 123 }).pipe(delay(2000));
let getFavourite = function (userId) {
  return of({ someData: 'someData: ' + userId }).pipe(delay(1000));
};

userLocation$
  .pipe(switchMap((data) => getFavourite(data.userId)))
  .subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```