# In Angular, declarative and reactive code is very hard to read. Or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Im trying to learn to write Angular more declarative and reactive. I have multiple components depending on pretty much same data from API, so Im saving the data on the service and once in the component, as I understand I need to also handle the scenario where user arrived, say, by a link and thus there's no data saved on a service yet. Can anyone experienced with Angular just review this code snippet and tell me what am I doing right and wrong? Here's an example:

Service:

```
  emails$ = new BehaviorSubject<IConstructorEmail[]>(null);
  async getAllEmails() {
    this.emails$.next(
      await lastValueFrom(
        this.dataService.get(`/api/constructors/emails`).pipe(
          map((res) => res.data),
          catchError((error) => {
            this.errorService.throw(error);
            return of(null);
          })
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Component:

```
  routeParams$: Observable<ParamMap> = this.route.queryParamMap;
  email$: Observable<IConstructorEmail> = this.routeParams$.pipe(
    switchMap((params) => {
      return this.constructorService.emails$.value
        ? this.constructorService.emails$.pipe(map((emails) => emails.find((email) => email._id === params.get('email'))))
        : this.constructorService.getEmail(params.get('email'));
    })
  );
  previewSource$: Observable<string> = combineLatest([this.routeParams$, this.email$]).pipe(
    switchMap(([params, email]) => this.gdriveService.getFileBody(email.translations[params.get('lang')]))
  );
```

Comment: You are mixing Promises and Observables, you should use only Observables. Specifically, you should get rid of this `await lastValueFrom()`

Comment: @JSONDerulo, why though? It seems perfect replacement for a subscribe, which needs to be instantly unsubscribed. I could do .pipe(take(1)).subscribe() instead, but this led me sometimes to quite nested callbacks

Comment: You can avoid nesting with `switchMap()` operator. I would suggest reading more about advanced RxJS techniques. Promises and Observables are not designed to work together, it is not a good practice to mix them. It can cause some issues which can be hard to fix.

Comment: @JSONDerulo, thank you. I will look for advanced RxJS information.

Comment: where do you call `getAllEmails` ?
what is your logic? what should be the difference between `getEmail()` and `emails$` with a filter ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree the way you have your current code is hard to read.  It really does take some time to shift your mind into the reactive paradigm and get used to rxjs.

Generally speaking, you want to design observables that emit exactly the data you need. That data may be sync or async; it may be cached or not, but to the subscriber, it doesn't matter.  He subscribes, and will receive the correct data, ideally without needing to do a lot of manipulation for it to be useful.

Also, in general, you don't want to subscribe in your service, but rather expose an observable (*or a method that returns an observable*) that consumers will subscribe to.  This allows your observables to be lazy and only "do work" when there is actually a subscriber interested in the data.

---

In your case, your component needs an email that may or may not have already been fetched.  However, the component shouldn't really need to know if the service has the data yet or not; it should just subscribe to the data it needs and the service should emit it when it's available.

In your service, you can declare an observable that emits the array of emails like this (*let's leave out error handling for now*):

```js
// service
private allEmails$ = this.dataService.get(`/api/constructors/emails`);
```

Then, you can expose a method that returns a single email like this:

```js
getEmail(id: string) {
   return this.allEmails$.pipe(
      map(emails => emails.find(e => e.id === id)
   );
}
```

Now, in the component, you just subscribe to the `getEmail()` method:

```js
// component
private emailId$ = this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
   map(params => params.get('email')),
   distinctUntilChanged(),
);

email$ = this.emailId$.pipe(
   switchMap(id => this.service.getEmail(id)
);
```

Notice, the component doesn't care whether the data is ready or not, it just subscribes and receives the data when it's available.  Notice with this implementation, the "getAllEmails" endpoint is hit each time `getEmail()` is subscribed to. To cache the initial response and prevent multiple calls to this endpoint, we can use `shareReplay(1)`:

```js
private allEmails$ = this.dataService.get(`/api/constructors/emails`).pipe(shareReplay(1));
```

This is just a basic implementation, but hopefully it helps to see how some of these rxjs puzzle pieces fit together.

Comment: Here's another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69688433/1858357) that explains how to implement a declarative pattern in rxjs.

Comment: Very much appreciated. This is what I was looking for.